# View filter settings: how to implement [TODAY] - 6 months

Tags: 2013, filter, view

I am building a SharePoint 2013 portal. I have a custom list. On this list I try to modify the default view. I would like to change the filter settings. I would like to show only the items between today and the last half jaar. How can I implement this? I know I can use the tag [TODAY]. But how do I calculate the date for 6 months back.[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried using [today]-180?

Comment: thanks this works. there is only one issue. A half year is not a fixed number of 180 days.

Comment: I know, but as far as I know you can only use a fixed number of days.