# View showing new list items

Tags: web-part, list-view, filter, view

Is there a view (or a way) that show new items only to a list?  My goal is to have a "New Items" list, or view that will be updated automatically shows any thing within the past 24 hours.  Filtered view in a web part won't do it so I'm wondering if there is another way.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple: You want to filter the Created column using the following function [Today]-1

Step 1: Go to Library tab -> Modify View for your list
Step 2: Go to the Filter section ->

- Select the Created column

  Select is greater than or equal to

  Enter [Today]-1 in the textbox

Step 3: Click Ok

[image]

Another Example:

[View filter settings: how to implement [TODAY] - 6 months](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/97857/view-filter-settings-how-to-implement-today-6-months)

Comment: Thanks.  So this will automatically update?  Let say I used it in a Web Part, would the web part have to be updated?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes. The listview results will update on its own.

Comment: worked like a charm.  Thanks!